# How to trace a specific endpoint on source System.Net

Tags: wcf, filter, trace, system.diagnostics, system.net

I'm trying to setup tracing for a specific endpoint in my WCF application.
I've tried with Filters on the "messageLogging" element in servicemodel, but it doesn't seem to apply on the sources System.Net and System.Net.Sockets.

I can't run tracing on all endpoints in production since it will add up to much storage. Doesnt anyone know how to filter the output to the listener to only include traffic on one specific endpoint?

My web.config looks like this:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net">
        <listeners>
          <add name="TraceFile"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="TraceFile"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="C:\Temp\TracingSystemNet.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="TraceFile" /> 
    </sharedListeners>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Can you try adding filters for message loggin https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967569(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Yes, i have tried that. but the sources I trace from didnt seem to be affected by this.